# ServiceTestRule: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, android-service, android-instrumentation

I have created class to test `Service` which uses `ServiceTestRule`. I am getting an exception while I try to retrieve a System Service object using `context.getSystemService(Context.SYSTEM_SERVICE_NAME)`.

StackTrace of Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:200)
at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:114)
at android.content.ClipboardManager$2.<init>(ClipboardManager.java:69)
at android.content.ClipboardManager.<init>(ClipboardManager.java:69)
at android.app.ContextImpl$11.createService(ContextImpl.java:405)
at android.app.ContextImpl$ServiceFetcher.getService(ContextImpl.java:297)
at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:1832)
at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getSystemService(ContextThemeWrapper.java:113)
at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5003)
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ClipboardServiceTest {

    private static final String ANY_LABEL = "Android";
    private static final String ANY_TEXT = "Android test rules";

    private Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext();

    @Rule
    public ServiceTestRule serviceTestRule = new ServiceTestRule();

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws TimeoutException {
        serviceTestRule.startService(new Intent(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext(), ClipboardService.class));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldShowClipboardViewOnCopyText() {
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText(ANY_LABEL, ANY_LABEL);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

        onView(withText(ANY_TEXT)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}
```

How possibly I can get system service objects (managers)?

Answer (score 0):

You usually get this error when you try to call something from a worker thread, while it is intended to be called from the main thread.
What worked for me is declaring a `@UiThreadTest` annotation on the test function like this:

```
@Test
@UiThreadTest
public void shouldShowClipboardViewOnCopyText() {
    ...
}
```